# Find and replace style attribute from the child element

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to iterate through the child elements and remove/modify some style attributes. My div are generated dynamically and i am able to get access to its id. My div can be

```
<div id="headline" style="position">
    <div style="text-align: center;">
        <b style="color: rgb(255, 204, 153);"><font size="5">Expansion Pack</font></b>
    </div>
</div>
```

or

```
<div id="headline" style="position">
    <div style="text-align: center;"> 
        <span style="color: rgb(255, 204, 153);">
            <font size="4">Expansion Pack</font>
        </span>
    </div>
</div>
```

I want to change the font size or color from the child elements of headline.

I know how to read all the elements inside parent div

```
$('#headline').find('*').each(function() {
     // do stuff
});
```

But how can i find the style attribute color and change the color or find the font size and change the size of the font.

Comment: Use jQuery `.css()`. [Check documentation](http://api.jquery.com/css/).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try the following [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/rsjfv58n/)

This will work for both cases

```
$('#headline').find('*').each(function (i, item) {
    var color = $(item).find("b,span");
    var font = $(item).find("font");

    $(color).css('color', 'red');
    $(font).css('font-size', '50px')
});
```

Comment: Pleasure, glad i could help

Answer (score 0):

If I get it right this is what you need to do:

```
$('#headline').each(function() {
     $(this).find('div').css({
       'font-color': 'blue',
       'font-family': 'arial',
       ...
     });
     $(this).find('font').css({
       'font-color': 'red',
       'font-family': 'roboto',
       ...
     });
});
```

Or you can get style value with:

```
var font-size = $(this).find('div').css('font-size');
```

Comment: In this way i am able to change the text color but font color is the same ,

Comment: You can change selector to star to affect all elements in your div, check out docs http://api.jquery.com/css/. Also I will update the answer.

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you are looking for?

```
#headline font {
    font-size:23px;
}
```

[**JSFiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/ope21u9o/)